# Google Consent Mode: Identify sessions with Consent on Google Analytics

Tags: session, google-analytics, analytics, google-tag-manager

We are using [Google Analytics consent mode (Beta)](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9976101?hl=en) which is currently in Beta. If I understand correctly, for page views without consent, each page view is considered as a new sessions since there will not be any session cookie.

Is there a way to filter only sessions where user has given consent? We want to use the number of sessions in order to calculate our conversion rates.

Answer (score 0):

tags fired without cookie consent sends anonymised data to GA. This means that data sent to GA without analytics_storage granted are considered 'cookie-less' hits which are stored in GA but are not included in any reports.